# How do I include visible spaces in code listing in table

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am writing an asciidoc document to be rendered in html that includes a table in which several cells include code listings. I mark those cells as "a|" and include the listing between `----` lines. I would like to make visible the spaces in quoted strings "like␣this" in the code listing. I replaced the spaces with `&blank;` characters, but that doesn't work; it just outputs `&blank;` where the space was. I also tried writing a passthrough with `+++&blank;+++`, but that doesn't work either.

How can I write visible space characters in code listings in tables?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to introduce the listing with `[source,subs="+macros"]` instead of `----`. Asciidoc frequently involves magic.